# ERROR discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "join" is not found

Tags: python, discord

i been trying to make a music bot to get some practice in python so i follow this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHZlvRr9KxM&t=1s and the code gives me this error:

- ERROR   discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None
  discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "join" is not found

```
PS D:\PROGRAMACION\DiscordBot>  & 'C:\Users\roysy\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.10.exe' 'c:\Users\roysy\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.18.2\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '63393' '--' 'd:\PROGRAMACION\DiscordBot\roydiscordbot.py'
d:\PROGRAMACION\DiscordBot\roydiscordbot.py:10: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'setup' was never awaited
  cogs[i].setup(client)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
2022-11-14 23:52:28 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
2022-11-14 23:52:29 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: e200f5ebad65ef9ad9f0a99f7b32409b).
2022-11-14 23:52:46 ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "join" is not found
2022-11-14 23:52:48 ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "join" is not found
2022-11-14 23:52:51 ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "play" is not found
2022-11-14 23:52:54 ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "disconnect" is not found
```

[image]

As I understand it, it could be a syntax error, but I've been thinking about it and rewriting everything, but I still haven't got a solution. If you can help me, that would be amazing. Thank you.

i've been using visual studio code

Code roydiscordbot.py:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import music
cogs = [music]

client =  discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', 
intents= discord.Intents.all())

for i in range(len(cogs)):
   cogs[i].setup(client)

client.run ('TOKEN')
```

Code Music.py:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music (commands.Cog):
   def __init__(self, client): self.client = client
   @commands.command() 
   async def join(Self,ctx):
      if ctx.author.voice is None:
        await ctx.send ("No estas en un Canal de Voz!")
      voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
      if ctx.voice_client is None:
        await voice_channel.connect()
      else:
        await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
  @commands.command()
  async def disconnect(Self,ctx):
     await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
  @commands.command()
  async def play(Self,ctx,url):
    ctx.voice_client.stop()
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 - reconnect_streamed 1 - 
    reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': "bestaudio"}
    vc = ctx.voice_client
    with youtube_dl.YotubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extact_info(url, download=False)
        url2 = info['format'][0]['url']
        source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
        vc.play(source)
  @commands.command()
  async def pause(Self,ctx,url):
      await ctx.voice_client.pause()
      await ctx.send("Pausa")
  @commands.command()
  async def resume(Self,ctx,url):
     await ctx.voice_client.resume()
     await ctx.send("Continua")
```

async def setup(client):
client.add_cog(music(client))

Comment: post the full error message

Comment: ready, i edit the main post and add an image

Comment: no images. text only